# Relation of the Number of Instances and Attributes for Classification

Tags: weka

In my dataset the number of instances is about 200 and each of them is described by about 600 attributes.  Each of the instances are labelled (Yes, No) and I'm trying to test different classifiers (k-NN, Naive-Bayes, j48).

It is very difficult to generate more instances, is there any minimum for the number of instances in relation to the number of attributes?

I should reduce attributes with Feature Selection, but if I had less attributes, which would be a reasonable number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether the number of features can be reduced comes down to the complexity of the problem, but some trial and error (or automated feature extraction methods) could determine if the number of features could be reduced without losing accuracy.

As reported in [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51490/how-large-a-training-set-is-needed), there are some guides or rules-of-thumb that could be used for preparing sufficient data for the model.  Some of the advice here included:

- At least six times the number of features as training cases
- At least three times the number of features per class

Hope this Helps!